# sorting the treeview tkinter column without clicking on the column header

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program where there is a customer record log. The program has the ability to enter the time and the client. This data is stored in the database. I can't sort the time without clicking on the column header. I wanted that when entering the time and the name of the client, and clicking on the save button, the time was sorted. I get the time, sort it, but the move() method does not move the elements to the positions I need.

This is part of the code. In the sort_time() method, I'm trying to sort the time.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import datetime

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.create_calendar()
        self.create_journal()
        self.create_button()

    def create_calendar(self):
        self.journal_frame = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, 
             highlightthickness=5, highlightbackground='red')
        self.journal_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')
        self.button_frame = tk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1, 
             highlightthickness=5, highlightbackground='red')
        self.button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def insert(self):
        self.tree.insert('', END, values=(self.c_time.get(), 
                          self.e_fio.get()))

    def sort_time(self):
        time = [(self.tree.set(i,0), i) for i in 
                       self.tree.get_children('')]
        spisok_time = [time[x][0] for x in range(len(time))]
        sorted_spisok = sorted(spisok_time, key=lambda y: 
                          datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M'))
        spisok_new_time = [(sorted_spisok[z], str(z+1)) for z in 
                            range(len(sorted_spisok))]
        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(spisok_new_time):
            self.tree.move(k, '', index)

    def create_journal(self):
        columns = ('time', 'client')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.journal_frame, columns=columns, 
                                  show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.tree.heading('time', text='Time', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('client', text='Client', anchor='center')
        self.tree.column('#1', width=50, stretch=True, anchor='e')
        self.tree.column('#2', width=250, stretch=False, 
                            anchor='center')

    def create_button(self):
        self.b_sort = tk.Button(self.journal_frame, text='Sort', 
                                 command=self.sort_time)
        self.b_sort.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='e')
        self.l_time = tk.Label(self.button_frame, text='Time:')
        self.l_time.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        time = ['8:00', '8:30', '9:00', '9:30', '10:00', '10:30', 
                 '11:00', '11:30',
                 '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', 
                  '14:30', '15:00', '15:30',
              '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', 
                 '19:00', '19:30']
        self.c_time = ttk.Combobox(self.button_frame, values=time, 
                                     width=5)
        self.c_time.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.l_fio = tk.Label(self.button_frame, text='Name:')
        self.l_fio.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.e_fio = tk.Entry(self.button_frame, width=20)
        self.e_fio.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.b_save = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text='Save', 
                                 command=self.insert)
        self.b_save.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky='e')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    win = Main(root)
    win.pack()
    root.title('Вывод данных')
    root.geometry('1500x800+100+100')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What output do you get and what exactly do you expect ? Note well, that the community standard is a [mre] and you can learn about it by taking the [tour] and in [ask]. As your question currently is written, you will need luck that someone is dedicated enough to code enough context to make your snippet work and still is motivated enough to solve your issue, which is unlikely. Please consider to [edit] your question in order to get help.

Comment: This is the code. I can't sort the time after pressing the save key or after pressing the "sort" button

Comment: Is sqlite or tkcalendar needed for your issue ?

Comment: Each date should have its own log, which is stored in the database. I should be able to select a date in the calendar and a log opens on that date.

Comment: The logic in the ```sort_time()``` is completely wrong. I'll answer if you edit the question for the [mre] guide.

Comment: relent 95, I reduced the code by as much as possible

Comment: You need to write like "@relent95" to notify a commenter like me.

Comment: @relent95, thanks for the help. I realized what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `sort_time()`, you sorted only timestamps into the `sorted_spisok`, lost the information on the order of item identifiers, and put arbitrary identifiers into the `spisok_new_time`.

So, sort the entire rows including item identifiers like this.

```
...
    def sort_time(self):
        rows = [(self.tree.set(i,0), i) for i in 
                       self.tree.get_children('')]
        sorted_rows = sorted(rows, key=lambda row: 
                          datetime.strptime(row[0], '%H:%M'))
        for index, (_, id) in enumerate(sorted_rows):
            self.tree.move(id, '', index)
...
```